Indexing performance of large nested array in Elasticsearch documents
We have a lot of Elasticsearch documents that have a field that contains a huge array of small objects with a handful of properties. This is to have precomputed values for a sort order based on a composite key composed of many fields on the document. We have noticed that in this setup, while good for searching in our case, documents are composed of a great many Lucene docs and are rather heavy for Elasticsearch to index.
Is there a downside to having documents that are composed of many Lucene docs and, if so, what would be alternative solutions to this setup?
Is it optimal for indexing to have one primary shard of our heavily indexing index per node and no replica's? What would then be better for indexing performance, having more CPUs per node or more nodes with fewer CPUs each (e.g. 2 nodes with 8 CPUs each vs. 4 nodes with 4 CPUs each)?
